# Python HTTP Error 500

Tags: python

I have this python code which gets data from this site. When Thread(for function, not class) is being used it shows HTTP Error 500, other wise when its not being used it shows normally. It's not the whole, just few snippets

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request    
def getData(self):
        dataRequest = Request('http://google.com')
        dataResponse = urlopen(dataRequest)
        dataData = dataResponse.read()

        jsonData = loads(dataData)

    ...
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: I seriously doubt...it's working fine...i don't know why you've used self,and jsonData

Comment: @Ajay As I mentioned, Its a snippet, I got a whole class and I doubt you read what I said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch and read the contents of the `Http error` like

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request    
def getData(self):

try:
    dataRequest = Request('http://google.com')
    dataResponse = urlopen(dataRequest)
    dataData = dataRespons
    jsonData = loads(dataData)


except urllib2.HTTPError, error:
    contents = error.read()
    print contents
```